# Considerable slowdown due to 40 boolean columns?

Tags: mysql, normalization

I'm trying to add musical style columns to an event table and from what I've gathered this can be either done by adding a column for each musical style or by doing a many-to-many table relation which I don't want because I want each event returned only once in a table. Do you think that having that many boolean columns in a row, that I would face considerable database slowdown? (Data will only be read by the users).
Thank you :)

Comment: 40 booleans for style is a bad design. Please read up on database normalization. What happens when you have to add a new style? SCHEMA CHANGE! Not a good plan.

Comment: If by data normalization you mean relational database, I don't think that's what I want :/
Let's say a person searches for an event that has Latino and Reggae music, and one event has both in it, will the same event be returned in a list twice in a list? From what I've read and asked, yes.

Comment: there are ways to mitigate that, if only by doing a `GROUP BY line_id`... but the performance of that would indeed be lower.

Comment: @puf It entirely depends on how you query. To remove duplicates I would use an `EXISTS` clause, this is a standard way to handle this type of thing, and performs well.

Comment: Hmm, well it wouldn't exactly be a duplicate as both rows would be identical except for that one column from which I would have to join the two musical styles from 2 rows into one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The columns will not slow down the database per se, but keep in mind that adding a boolean column for every music style is very poor design. Over time, the possible musical styles in your application are likely to change: maybe new ones must be added, redundant or useless ones must be removed, whatever. With your proposed design, you'd have to modify your database structure to add the new columns to the table. This is usually painful, error-prone, and you'll also have to go over all your queries to make sure they don't break because of the new structure.

You should design your database schema so that it's flexible enough to allow for variance over time in the contents of your application. For example, you could have a master table with one row for every musical style, defining its ID and its name, description etc. Then, a relationships table that contains the relationship between an entity (event, if I understood your question correctly) and a music style from the master table. You enforce consistency by putting foreign keys in place, to ensure data is always clean (eg. you cannot reference a music style that is not in the master table). This way ,you can modify the music styles without touching anything in the database structure.

Reading a bit on [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) will help you a lot; you don't have to go all the way to have a fully normalized database, but understanding the principles behind will allow you to design efficient and clean database structures.

Comment: While this approach makes it impossible to add new music styles *dynamically*, running an `ALTER` script is hardly painful or error-prone... a significantly larger pain point is that denormalized tables are notoriously hard to write join-based requests against.

Comment: Okay, I will re-read everything. Is it however possible, to search for - let's say 90s + jazz. In this case, one event would have both of these musical styles. This would likely return two rows, but is it possible to make the "table list" that is shown to the user to show that particular event only once, with 90s + jazz in one column?
Edit: I seee now: "Group by"

Comment: @pufAmuf: sure you can, using for example GROUP BY clause or GROUP_CONCAT (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) which will return you the values of a column in all rows, separated by commas .

Comment: Excellent! I have tons of reading ahead of me but I'm excited :) Thanks everyone :)

Answer (score 1):

The likely answer is **no**

Having multiple boolean columns in a row should not significantly slow down DB performance; assuming your indices are set up appropriately.

**EDIT:** That being said it may be optimal to assign a details table and `JOIN` to it to get this data... but you said you didn't want to do that.

I assume you want to do something like have an event row with a bunch of columns like "isCountry", "isMetal", "isPunk" and you'll query all events marked as

```
isPunk = 1 OR isMetal = 1
```

or something like that.

The weakness of this design is that to add/remove musical styles you need to change your DB schema. 
An Alternative is a `TBLMusicalStyles` with an `ID` and a `Name`, then a `TBLEventStyles` which will just contains `EventID` and `StyleID`

Then you could join them and just search on the styles table... and adding and removing styles would be relatively simple.

Comment: Thanks Matthew, I will go ahead and try that :)

Answer (score 1):

The performance of requests that do not involve musical styles will not be affected.

If your columns are properly indexed, then requests that involve finding lines that match client-provided musical styles should actually be *faster*.

However, all other requests that involve musical styles will be significantly slower, and also harder to write. For instance, "get all lines that share at least one style with the current line" would be a much harder request to write *and* execute.